Any Alternatives for Prajapatya penance
Prajapatya penance is still valid in Kaliyug, because we live in a modern world and we have several responsibilities (like jobs). If at all one should perform Prajapatya penance, what can one do?

Depends on the pāpa. Apart from that, three pādakṛcchra is equivalent to 1 prājāpatya. In Kaliyuga, it's not like you may not take breaks, trips, etc., similarly it's not tough to make time for prājāpatya, if it's important. After all, it is for one's own self, not for someone other, in a usual case.

Pādakṛcchra means ? and what is the duration for each Pādakṛcchra ?

The format of both pādakṛcchra and prājāpatya is same.
It's just that each of the three-day divisions of latter are reduced to one day each for the former. In other words, you need to perform activity X, Y, Z, W for three days each respectively, totalling 12 days in prājāpatya. But in pādakṛcchra, the same activities are performed on 1 day each respectively, totalling 4 days.

That is why 3 pādakṛcchra is equivalent to 1 prājāpatya kṛcchra.
